# lithiation between thiophene with n-buthyllithium

Tags: organic-chemistry

I just want to know if an electrophilic aromatic substitution reaction between n-buthyllitium and thiophene takes place, where the lithium ion of n-buthyllithium acts as an electrophile and reacts with thiophene during lithiation.

Is this true?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. 2-Lithiothiophene is well-behaved and stable in solution.

Comment: Let me reformulate. I don't understand the concept of lithiation between a thiophene containing molecule (2,2’-(1,3-Butadiyne-1,4 diyl)dithiophene) and n-buthyllithium. My guess is that a directed ortho metalation reaction takes place, but I don't understand how.

Comment: pKa of thiophene at the 2 position is approx 33